# How to get Entity based on member object's field value rather than member objects ID

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have three classes and code for the same is displayed below

**Enquiry Class**:

```
@Entity
public class Enquiry 
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private String name;

  private String discription;

  private int status;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date enquiryDate;
}
```

**User Class**:

```
 @Entity
 public class User 
 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   private String name;

   private String userId;

   private String password;
 }
```

**UserEnquiryUserEnquiryMapping Class**:

```
@Entity
public class UserEnquiryMapping 
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @ManyToOne
   private User user;

   @ManyToOne
   private Enquiry enquiry;
}
```

Now suppose if we want to get `Enquiry(s)` for a particular `User` than we can easily get it by passing a `User` object and hibernate will generate query by using `id` field from `User` object, and code for the same scenario is mentioned below.

```
EntityManager entityManager = session.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<UserEnquiryMapping> criteria = builder.createQuery(UserEnquiryMapping.class);
Root<UserEnquiryMapping> root = criteria.from(UserEnquiryMapping.class);
criteria.select(root);
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("user"), user));

userEnquiries = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

But my requirement is I want to get User enquiries on the basis of user's name or we can say that I want to generate query like this

```
 Select * from UserEnquiryMapping inner join Enquiry on UserEnquiryMapping.Enquiry_ID = Enquiry.ID inner join User on UserEnquiryMapping.User_ID = User.ID where User.name="Test";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: builder.equal(root.get("user").get("name"),user.getName());

Comment: Thanks budy it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.equal(root.get("user").get("name"),user.getName());
```

glad it help you!

Comment: Thank you very much! It saved my day! Even though the problem is not the same as the question haha It helped me to understand how the Criteria API deals with entity attributes that are Entity objects.